# How to send GCM messages to multiple devices at a time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send same message to multiple devices in android using GCM. Currently i am able to send push notification to my device as i am explicitly specifying my registration ID in PHP code. But i want to send it to multiple devices  so how can i do this???
Any help or idea are highly appreciated.

Please guide for this
Thanks

Comment: Are you storing your list of regids in a database?

Comment: I withdraw my answer as I don't have enough experience with how to implement the server side. But I'd recommend you to go here take a read about GCM: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Accept the #&%@ answer!

Answer (score 40):

What you should do is send multiple registrations Ids (up to 1000 at once) when you send your message to GCM, and you will need to use JSON as your request format.

You can read more about that here: 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#downstream

You will need to add your list of Id's to the **registration_ids** field:

> A string array with the list of devices (registration IDs) receiving the message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration IDs. To send a multicast message, you must use JSON. For sending a single message to a single device, you could use a JSON object with just 1 registration id, or plain text (see below). Required.

Here is an example request from their docs:

Here is a message with a payload and 6 recipients:

```
{ "data": {
   "score": "5x1",
   "time": "15:10"
  },
  "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```