# create JSON object in PHP and send this through Firebase push notification

Tags: php, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am new to php. i am implementing Firebase push notification service in PHP .

The required json object is like

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Now in firebase i have to send my data in this format but i am not sure how to make JSON object of this data and use this object in firebase .

And if I want to use Array of IDs then how this will work?

As per official firebase documentation they didn't define method to use array of ID's.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream

Comment: To send to a list of devices, you'd send an array of ids: `"to": ["token1", "token2", "token3"]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511167/how-to-send-gcm-messages-to-multiple-devices-at-a-time

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send a POST with PHP you could use cURL:

```
<?php
    $firebase_url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $message = [
        "data" => [
            "score" => "5x1",
            "time" => "15:10"
        ],
        "to": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
    ];

    $json_message = json_encode($message);

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $firebase_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_message)
    ]);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print $result;
```

I will recommend using Guzzle which is a third party library and cleaner and more usable/understandable. To install it:

```
php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

And some examples here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much . let me check it. but tell me if i want to send msg to multiple id's then how we will change it ?

Comment: and why you change 

{ }

to 

[ ]

Comment: The thing is JSON is not a data structure in PHP. So, you define an array and then you format that array as a valid JSON string with `json_encode`. Also, you could create an object and implement it as `JsonSerializable`, but you will end in a similar scenario as `json_encode` but could be more robust for OOP cases.

Comment: The problem is in sending message to multiple ids

i change "to" field to "registration_ids"  but still not works

Comment: As far as I understand, you should hit each message individually, there is no way to do a Batch send. So wrap all the code above inside a `foreach ($msg_array => $msg) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array in a same format that you want to sent to Firebase like bellow

```
$arr = ['data'=> [
        'score'=> "5x1",
        'time'=> "15:10"
        ],
        "to" => "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
      ];
```

and then use the php function json_encode(var); and it will return you the json object.

```
json_encode($arr)
```

> and if i want to use Array of id then how this will work.
>   I am not sure about this.